# Is there any major difference between acceleration of solid propelled and liquid propelled rockets during launch

Tags: spacex, propulsion, launch-vehicle, isro, acceleration

Few days ago, ISRO launched its PSLV-C53, which had solid first stage. (Clip [here](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxzaQl7ge8n1p6pY_XWkZ4feH2WFhSub76))

Also, the SpaceX's starlink launched on 24th July, 2022, having liquid first stage. (Clip [here](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxhiMaMwXMpL_7tYWV7maYtkynoywiVjDC))

Is there any **major difference between the initial acceleration** given by these two different technologies?

Comment: When you say initial acceleration, do you mean first few milliseconds, first few seconds or first few dozen seconds ? I don't think that there is any major difference if one considered only first few seconds of acceleration.

Comment: Let's say first few milliseconds. As solid propelled rockets ingnite like an explosion but liquid engines have throttling. Am i right?

Comment: I think the spin up, ignition and throttling or just ignition all happen very quickly and the rocket (solid or liquid) remains clamped to the launch pad until the thrust reaches a preset value where upon the clamps release and the rocket launches.